# Convert ASCII Value directly to the literal integer value

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm reading in a text file for a simulated compiler, and I'm trying to tokenize all the literals. When I realize it's a number value, I'm trying to store the number. However, since the entire line I'm reading from is a string, I only get the ASCII value for the number (i.e. 0 becomes 48), when I really need the value 0. Is there any way to obtain the literal value from the string/char I'm looking at?

example:

```
std::string IR = "set 0, read"            
int currentIRIndex = 4 // (looking at the 0 char)
```

`IR[currentIRIndex]` is 0 if I call it from the `<<` operator, and 48 (the ASCII value of 0) if I assign it to an integer.

Comment: Are you looking to convert one character at a time, or parse as many digits as you can find?

Comment: Though there are many (better) ways to convert a string to a number, I'm surprised you didn't at least consider `cout << IR[currentIRIndex] -48 << "\n";`

Comment: I'm only worried about the current number I'm looking at. @DavidO Oh my gosh....what an easy solution. Talk about functional fixedness..... >_<

Comment: We all have those moments, I suppose. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int v = IR[currentIRIndex] - '0';
```

this will give you the literal value

Comment: This didn't seem to work a few minutes ago, but now seems to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @LeoVannini: Note that this does not always work for the alphabet, but always works for the ten latin numeric digits.

Comment: this work in your use case with 1 char as a number, if you work with number > 9 this will not and you'll have to use solution to transform a string in int like atoi or boost lexical_cast or direclty with the stream